# MariaDB: varchar column size limit problem for unique index

Tags: mysql, indexing, mariadb, innodb, varchar

I have a problem building a unique index for a 3 million row table in MariaDB. It has over half a million utf-8 string keys I want to look up. The strings have to be utf-8 because they contain English, German, Japanese, Spanish and Cyrillic characters. Using an index that results in a linear search will be probably be too slow.

The problem is that the maximum total length of utf-8 varchars in a column is 21,844 characters. The allowed number of individual chars is orders of magnitude less then the number of used keys, and the keys are all multi-character. (Note that the table to be indexed is of fixed size in this case.)

I have found no examples online that address this situation. All examples use multi-column unique keys where it is assumed no individual column will overrun the total varchar size limit.

Is there any way to use MariaDB/MySQL for this dataset? Given that these SQL databases can manage hundreds of millions of rows, there should be a way to efficiently index a relatively small table of only 3 million rows.

Comment: Instead of add index on very long string why not index its hashed value.that way you can reduce index length. Or using full-text index

Comment: You are saying the column is `TEXT CHARACTER SET utf8` and you want to have a `UNIQUE` index on it?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [generated column](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-generated-columns.html) to create a hash of the text column and [create a unique index](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-secondary-indexes.html) on this hash. Adding a partial non-unique index on the text additionally will help the searching.

Collisions of hashes are theoretically possible, but in 3 million is seems unlikely.

Comment: [mariadb generated columns manual reference](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/generated-columns/)

Comment: This response basically answered my question. Thank you very much for a useful and simple answer.